# WireGuard Android client not building

Tags: c++, build, android-ndk, wireguard

When building the client gives the following error:

> arghandling.c
> 'stdlib.h' file not found [x86_64]

I understand that it does not see the header files of the C++ standard libraries. Reading official instructions did not help.
SDK 33.0.2, NDK installed 25.2.9519653. If I create a new project from the standard android studio template with c++ then the build goes without problems